# Converting string values to integer values

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, python-3.x, integer

Is there any "easy" way to convert a string of **letters** to an integer value? I know a method that would work, but it would be very tedious. Oh and in Python, I forgot to mention that. It would be like "ABC" = 123

Comment: What would "XYZ" translate to?

Comment: Yes, that's quite a good question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Pre-define* a dictionary that maps letters to numbers:

```
d = {'A': '1', 'B': '2', 'C': '3', 'D': '4',
     'E': '5', 'F': '6', 'G': '7', 'H': '8',
     'I': '9', 'J': '10', 'K': '11', 'L': '12',
     'M': '13', 'N': '14', 'O': '15', 'P': '16',
     'Q': '17', 'R': '18', 'S': '19', 'T': '20',
     'U': '21', 'V': '22', 'W': '23', 'X': '24',
     'Y': '25', 'Z': '26'}
```

Then you can convert with:

```
int(''.join(d[c] for c in 'ABC'))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print ([ord (c) - ord ('A') + 1 for c in 'ABC'])
```

N.B. Rob's answer is better... (upto the 'i' ;=))

Comment: Thanks, this is what i needed

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is underspecified. There are literally infinite functions that will convert `'ABC'` to `123`, including this one:

```
def letter2number(s):
    return 123
```

If you want to covert the strings by concatenating the decimal digits of the letter's offset into the alphabet, this one might work for you. Note that you can't round-trip the value: `24` could be `X` or it could be `BD`.

```
def letter2number(s):
    return int(''.join('%d'%(ord(ch)-ord('A')+1) for ch in s))

assert letter2number('ABC') == 123
assert letter2number('XYZ') == 242526
```

Comment: So add 100 to each code (to keep it simple) and then glue together.

Comment: But then `'ABC'` won't yield `123`, which was a requirement.

Comment: Indeed. So it would need to be a variable lenght code, perhaps with the 0 as extension indicator. But I guess that's not what OP was looking for...